# WebView automatically adds the file:// before URL

Tags: ios, webview

I have added the custom URL Scehme in my application. like myapp://

So whenever it detect myapp://http://google.com. it should redirect to my app. and how URL on the webview.

At  Appdelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *strURL = [url.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"myapp://" withString:@""];

    WebViewController *objWebView = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    objWebView.url=strURL;
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:objWebView animated:YES completion:NULL];

    return YES;
}
```

But when I load request with that URL. it appends file:// before that URL how can i load URL in web view.

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    NSLog(@"%@",request.URL); // O/P :  htpp//google.com
```

ON `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`

```
    -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    {

  NSLog(@"%@",request.URL);  file://htpp//google.com
         return true;

    }
```

At the end it fails with the error

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not
>   found on this server." UserInfo=0x7983bb30
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file://htpp//google.com,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://htpp//google.com,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this
>   server., NSUnderlyingError=0x78fbbe70 "The requested URL was not found
>   on this server."}

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? i'm also facing same problem

Comment: I would also like to know if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is wrong. what is `htpp//google.com` ? It should be  `http://google.com`

Comment: That is just a typo and irrelevant for the question in this particular case.